# SQLALchemy adjacency list get all parents

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here's an adjacency list example:

```
class TreeNode(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tree'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(id))
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)

    children = relationship("TreeNode",
                        cascade="all",
                        backref=backref("parent", remote_side=id)
                    )
```

Supposing I've got a simple linear structure:
(0)---->(1)---->(2)---->(3)

How do I get all ancestor nodes of a certain node? Something like node2.parents.all() that returns a list of nodes 0 and 1.

I tried to do this:

```
parents = relationship("TreeNode", cascade="all", primaryjoin="TreeNode.parent_id==TreeNode.id")
```

with no luck - it returns children instead of parents.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it using simple relationship. 
If you use MSSQL or Postgresql, instead try to create a ([Hybrid](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#join-dependent-relationship-hybrid)) attribute, which would leverage on [Query.cte](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.cte).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, I'll look it up - for now it seems to be a little bit dark. If someone else's stumbled on this, it's possible to use rather more exprensive thing which still does what I want:

```
@property
def parents(self):
    allparents = []
    p = self.parent
    while p:
        allparents.append(p)
        p = p.parent
    return allparents
```